# Flask: How can I store the connection details of clients [Inside NAT], so I can POST them a webhook later?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I want to make a `/subscribe` endpoint that will add the client to a list that will be notified with a webhook when an event happens. How can I get the data from flask needed to connect to the client later so I can then send a POST in requests later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can not store the connection details.

There is nothing called CONNECTION. It is just an HTTP request from one server to the other.

All HTTP requests are just messages that you (Browser or a server) sends to another server asking for something like "Can I view your website?" or "Can you send me this data?" etc.,

## Possible solution for you:

I have worked on webhooks for one of your products in our company and the best way to give the ability to create a webhook to your client is, asking for their endpoint.

**What I did:**

1. I ask the client for their endpoint so that I can call it whenever there is an event.
2. Ask them to create and share a secret_key so that no one else can call that endpoint other than you.
3. Call that endpoint using their secret_key whenever there is an event.

Above is just an outline of how it is done (Or at least how I did it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What format would they tell me their endpoint in? What kind of data do I need?

Comment: I don't know what your application is about. But, a webhook's endpoint generally would be an API endpoint where the client can take take request and process it however they want.

Comment: I'm writing a simple chat app and want to inform the user of new messages.

Comment: In that case what you may need to do is - 1. in messages.php, create a session for each active user. 2. Whenever someone sends a message to someone, store it. 3. Write another file called get_messages.php which returns all the messages for a conversation thread. 4. Write a JS function which sends an ajax message to get_messages.php in every 10 seconds or so and update the conversation box with the new messages if any. This is just a basic way of doing it but it should work if you are just getting started with coding.

Comment: Thanks. It was a Python client (should have mentioned that) but I achieved it by having a flask route that would not return any data until a message was sent, then had a high timeout on it. In the client I synchronously called it, using it as a blocker until there was a message.

Thanks for your help.